# How do I read in text from file, but ignore certain lines in C#?

Tags: c#

I am just learning C# and I need to read text from a file into an array, but ignore lines beginning with certain special characters. I am using ReadAllLines to read in the text.

What I am doing :

```
string file = openFileDialog1.FileName;
file_txtbx.Text = file;
try {
    test = File.ReadAllLines(file); // reads file into array
} catch (ArgumentNullException) {
}
```

Example of my text file used to read in text :

```
A
D
# Next is incorrect
C
```

Comment: When you use File.ReadAllLines then you solved one problem only to produce a new one.  Reading one line at a time with StreamReader.ReadLine() and adding the ones you like to a `List<string>` tends to get you write the correct code.  Do the basic first, take the shortcuts later when you learned when they appropriate.

Comment: Thank you! My instructor isn’t the best so I’ve been googling everything and ReadAllLines was the first one I came across that automatically loaded an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`File.ReadLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx) followed by `Where`:

```
var allLines = File.ReadLines(file).Where(s => !s.StartsWith("#")).ToArray();
```

This yields an array of all lines not starting in `"#"`.

**Note:** You should not catch `ArgumentNullException`, because it indicates a programming error. Instead you should check the values that you are about to pass to methods that could throw `ArgumentNullException` to avoid making a call that will throw the exception.

Answer (score 0):

To filter an array : **use Linq**

As ReadAllLines returns an array of `string`, you can simply filter this array using Linq method `Where` and test for the beginning of the string with `StartsWith()` :

```
// ...
test = file.ReadAllLines(file);
// return lines that don't start with '#'
var filteredLines = test.Where(line => !line.StartsWith("#"));
```

You can also add several conditions in the predicate (the `line => boolean expression`), using any logical operators and functions you need.

For instance, to also ignore lines starting with `//` :

```
// return lines that don't start with '#' and also that don't start with '//'
var filteredLines = file.ReadAllLines(file)
    .Where(line => !line.StartsWith("#") && !line.StartsWith("//"));
```

**Additional info :**

The type of `filteredLines` in these examples is `IEnumerable<string>`, meaning that you can use this result in a `foreach(string s in filteredLines)` , for instance.

Depending on what you do with it afterwards, if you prefer to have an array `string[]`, just add `.ToArray()`.

If you prefer to have a `List<string>`, just add `.ToList()`.

**Note :** you'll have to add `using System.Linq;` to the top of the .cs file, to be able to use the `Where`, `ToList`, and `ToArray` methods.

Comment: Excellent, this will come in handy in the future for more dynamic programs. Thank you !

Answer (score -1):

My solution was

```
test = file.ReadAllLines(file).Where(line => !string.Equals(line, "your string"));
```

this way you don't have to care about null , also if your comparison ignore upper/lowercase, you can do

```
test = file.ReadAllLines(file).Where(line => !string.Equals(line, "your string", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Comment: this will only remove the exact string from the the list. The character '#' is used for commenting (as in many text scripts), and so OP asked for the lines *beginning with* this special character